# MS SQL Update Numbers (ID) for each Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, identity

I have just created a column (Priority) in my SQL table.
I want to be able to set up a one time UPDATE that sets the ID's for each current Priority Cell for each Type of Genre for that AgendaType.

I have searched the web endlessly yet cannot seem to find what I am looking for.

So for example my Update would result in the following:

```
AgendaType | Genre | Priority
-------------------------------
Rock         Red     1
Rock         Red     2
-------------------------------
Rock         Blue    1
Rock         Blue    2
Rock         Blue    3
Rock         Blue    4
Rock         Blue    5
-------------------------------
Rock         Green   1
Rock         Green   2
Rock         Green   3
Rock         Green   4
-------------------------------
Rap          Red     1
Rap          Red     2
Rap          Red     3
Rap          Red     4
-------------------------------
Rap          Blue    1
Rap          Blue    2
-------------------------------
Rap          Green   1
Rap          Green   2
Rap          Green   3
```

Is this something I could do? If so any help or advice on this would be appreciated. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL @sgeddes

Comment: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/sequencesubset/

Comment: confused as to why someone has down voted. ahwell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using `row_number()` and a `common-table-expression`:

```
with cte as (
    select AgendaType, 
           Genre, 
           Priority,
           row_number() over (partition by AgendaType, Genre order by AgendaType) rn
    from yourtable
) 
update cte
set priority = rn
```

This creates a row number for each group of agendatype and genre.  Then the `update` is trivial.

Comment: I can't seem to do this "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near ')'." I like the idea though, Would the result be the same as the Desire Resut in my question?

Comment: @DJONES -- oops, I left out `as` -- should be `with cte as ...`

Comment: @DJONES -- and yes, run the `select` statement by itself to see.

Comment: do i not need to include priority in the select?

Comment: running the whole thing catches on Invalid column name 'Priority'.

Comment: hmm, it seems that all the cells in priority are just '1'

Comment: I appreciate your help by the way I'm just trying to figure this out I'm new to using 'With'

Comment: I sorted it!  row_number() over (partition by Id, AgendaId order by AgendaId) rn

Comment: @DJONES -- glad you figured it out!  And I don't know -- I ticked it up for you though :)